# storm-kafka - example application or a git link of a storm topology that maintains the kafka partition level ordering?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, hadoop2

I know, storm doesn't guarantee total ordering gurantee for kafka topics, but see in many documents, storm guarantees consumption/processing the messages maintaining the order at partition level.

I am looking for a sample storm topology, that consumes/processes the messages of a kafka topic maintaining the order of messages at a kafka partition level.. NOT Total Order!! ONLY partition level ordering guarantee.

please share if you know any sample application. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Apache Storm examples here? https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka

You may want to consider standard example and scale it based on your needs. Also, while defining Schema for the KafkaSpuout, you may want to output some key as part of the tuple and later use FieldG
rouping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @YaRiK

i am doing the field Grouping correctly. But, i am unsure why bolt is processing the records it accumulates in a jumbled order... !! 

Will storm bolt not really processes the records in the same order it receives ?

Comment: will a trident kafka spout help me ?

Comment: it should process in the order it receives only if you have only 1 bolt/spot per task. in this case it will act as "single threaded" application. The only other option i know of to enforce sequence is FieldGrouping. So please try first to set all parallelism hints to 1 and prove that the topology works the way you want. next check Kafka and make sure that messages that require sequence land on the same partition. You can do it by using consistent key in the producer code and/or implement Partitioner

Comment: @Raja if you found a solution to this problem of ensuring ordering at partition level while not making it single threaded, could you please share the solution. I am looking for similar thing with storm 1.0.1, trying to use windowing operation. But I need to ensure that messages from same partition end up on the same bolt and in the same order. Thank you.

Comment: @Pranav Shukla... there is not seperate programming i did to get partition level data ordering... storm-kafka api by default guarantees records are given in order at partition level! When i posted the question... i did not realize that our source itself is not giving records in order!